# sum over a list of tensors in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, cost-based-optimizer

I have a deep neural network where the weights between layers are stored in a list.

`layers[j].weights` I want to incluse the ridge penalty in my cost function. I need then to use something like 
`tf.nn.l2_loss(layers[j].weights**2 for j in range(self.n_layers))` i.e. the squared sum of all the weights.

In particular the weights are defined as:

```
>>> avs.layers
[<neural_network.Layer object at 0x10a4b2a90>, <neural_network.Layer object at 0x10ac85080>, <neural_network.Layer object at 0x10b0f3278>, <neural_network.Layer object at 0x10b0eacf8>, <neural_network.Layer object at 0x10b145588>, <neural_network.Layer object at 0x10b165048>, <neural_network.Layer object at 0x10b155ba8>]
>>>
>>> avs.layers[0].weights
<tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x10b026748>
>>>
```

How can I do that in tensorflow ?

Comment: I think you need to create a new tensor out of those weights and use that in the cost equation.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The standard way to sum a list of tensors is to use the [`tf.add_n()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/add_n) operation, which takes a list of tensors (each having the same size and shape) and produces a single tensor containing the sum.

For the particular problem that you have, I am assuming that each `layers[j].weights` could have a different size. Therefore you will need reduce each element down to a scalar before summing, e.g. using the [`tf.nn.l2_loss()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/l2_loss) function itself:

```
weights = [layers[j].weights for j in range(self.n_layers)]
losses = [tf.nn.l2_loss(w) for w in weights]
total_loss = tf.add_n(losses)
```

(Note however that when the values to be added are large, you may find it more efficient to calculate a sequence of [`tf.add()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/add) operations, since TensorFlow keeps the values of each of the `add_n` arguments in memory until *all* of them have been computed. A chain of `add` ops allows some of the computation to happen earlier.)

Comment: Using the standard Python built-in `sum()` is a shorter equivalent to a sequence of tf.add ops.

Answer (score 1):

The `tf.nn.l2_loss()` function returns a tensor with 0 dimensions.

But it's nice to not need to manually apply that to each weight tensor, so storing the weight tensors in a list is one way to solve the problem (as @mrry noted).

But rather than needing to write that out every time, what you could do is use the following function

```
def l2_loss_sum(list_o_tensors):
    return tf.add_n([tf.nn.l2_loss(t) for t in list_o_tensors])
```

In your case this would look like:

```
total_loss = l2_loss_sum([layers[j].weights for j in range(self.n_layers)])
```

Also, `tf.nn.l2_loss()` implicitly applies the squaring operation to the values as well as multiplying all the squared values by 1/2 , so were you use something like `tf.nn.l2_loss(layers[j].weights**2 for j in range(self.n_layers))` you would actually be raising the weights to the 4th power. As a result your derivative of this loss term would be strange: it wouldn't cancel the 1/2 to 1 (but would implicitly be doubling your β) and the weights would be cubed.